# Python drawing a circle based on a character in a list

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a circle using the Tkinter when I find an "O" inside a list of lists. This is meant to be loaded on top of a grid that I generated based off the same list. It just makes a coloured rectangle depending on what character is in the list. How can I load the circle for say a variable such as position = (1,1)  which would refer to the first character in the first list?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by just using the same cords to place the rectangles